# OAuth 1.0 Authentication in UNIX Shell Script

Tags: rest-api, oauth

I am new to Magento REST API. I have requirement of UNIX shell script

1. Authentication : To generate token for OAuth 1.0 Authentication. Please let me know how do I generate Access Token and Token Secret.
2. Also please let me know how do I call CURL command to pass consumer Key , Consumer secret, Access Token and Token Secret to call REST API to create new Products in Magento. I need to pass JSON file which contains multiple products. I tried this code but it giving error

I tried this code but it is giving error : The signature is invalid. Verify and try again

*url="my url"
encodedURL=$(urlencode $url)
ConsumerKey="my key"
encodedConsumerKey=$(urlencode $ConsumerKey)
ConsumerSecret="my secret"
encodedConsumerSecret=$(urlencode $ConsumerSecret)
AccessToken="my token"
encodedAccessToken=$(urlencode $AccessToken)
TokenSecret="my token secret"
encodedTokenSecret=$(urlencode $TokenSecret)
signature_method="HMAC-SHA256"
Nonce=$(openssl rand -base64 12)
Timestamp=$(date +%s)
PARAM=$(urlencode "oauth_consumer_key=$ConsumerKey&oath_nonce=$Nonce&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=$Timestamp&oath_token=$AccessToken&oauth_version=1.0")
encodedPARAM=$(urlencode "oauth_consumer_key=$encodedConsumerKey&oath_nonce=$Nonce&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=$Timestamp&oath_token=$encodedAccessToken&oauth_version=1.0")
signature=$(echo -n 'POST&'$encodedURL'&'$encodedPARAM|openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "$encodedConsumerSecret&$encodedTokenSecret" |base64)
encoded_signature=$(urlencode $signature)
PAYLOAD= ' my data'
curl -v  -X POST 

'my url' 

-H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="$ConsumerKey",oauth_token="$AccessToken",oauth_signature_method="$signature_method",oauth_timestamp="$Timestamp",oauth_nonce="$Nonce",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="$encoded_signature"" 

-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 

-d "${PAYLOAD}"*

Comment: Hope this will help you. URL :https://www.integerbyteblog.in/technology/magento-2-rest-api/

Comment: i tried this code but it is giving error : The signature is invalid. Verify and try again